# Как отправить сообщение всем подключенным клиентам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Как отправить сообщение всем подключенным клиентам, после того, как я его получил на сервер?

код сервера :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',3535))

print('[ Start Server ]')

while True:
    message = s.recv(128).decode()               
    print(message)
```

код клиента :

```
import socket


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while True:
    msg = input('введите текст сообщения : ')
     sock.sendto(msg.encode(), ('0.0.0.0',3535))
```